# Flutter for web - Where do I place images to use AssetImage?

Tags: flutter

I would like to display images by using `AssetImage` but I don't know where should I place them when it comes to Flutter for web.
Does anyone know where do I put those?

Comment: go to `<root>/examples/gallery` folder and see where they store any `*.png` files

Comment: I'm sorry I can't find that folder.

Comment: Yeah. Actually I found a way to load image. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way.
You just create assets folder under the web like so.

[image]